# Jinja2で自作オブジェクトを「文字列」と判定させる方法について、ドキュメントのどこかに説明がありますか？

Tags: python3, sphinx

問題そのものは解決していますが、手探りでPythhon/Sphinx/Jinja2を使っていることもあり、この問題の解決はかなり迷走していました。そのため、これに関連する知識を補強することを考えています。よろしくお願いします。

■質問
Jinja2で自作オブジェクトを「文字列」と認識させる方法は、以下の二つ

- オブジェクトを渡すのは諦めて文字列を渡す。
- unicodeクラスを継承したクラスを作る。

Q1: 後者についての説明、或いはこれを類推させる説明はドキュメントにありますか？

「あるとしたら、✕✕辺り」という対象範囲の推測でも喜びます。

■該当のテンプレート

sphinxの「genindex.html」を改良したのですのですが、そのテンプレートの追加部分です。

```
  5 {% macro kana_entry(kname) %}
  6   {%- if kname is string -%}
  7   {{ kname|e }}
  8   {%- else %}
  9   {%- for isruby, val in kname -%}
 10     {%- if isruby -%}
 11     <ruby><rb>{{ val[0]|e }}</rb><rp>（</rp>
 12     <rt>{{ val[1]|e }}</rt><rp>）<rp>
 13     </ruby>
 14     {%- else %}
 15     {{ val|e }}
 16     {%- endif %}
 17   {%- endfor %}
 18   {%- endif %}
 19 {% endmacro %}
```

上記の「if kname is string」ですが、自作クラスを「string」として判定させる場合は「unicode」クラスを継承されると上手く動きます。たまたま見つけた解決策なのですが、この「たまたま見つける」のケースを少なくしたいと考えています。

■ここまでの経緯
1．unittestでテストケースを作りながら開発。
2．テストには__eq__を使い、Jinja2へは__str__でデータを渡すことで、テスト時はデータ構造のチェックのみとする方法を採用。
3．unittestにはパスするが、make htmlでエラーになる現象に悩まされる。→回避策を採用
4．同じ自作クラスなのに想定通りに使えるクラスもある。これの気づいて条件の切り分け

3はあっさり書いていますが、問題のクラスは__iter__, __next__も実装していたこともあり、なかなか「unicodeクラスの継承」に気付けませんでした。

以上

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。

■unicodeクラス
ソースの該当箇所を遡って見たら、strクラスを（恐らくpython2との互換性のためだと思いますが）unicodeとしていました。

■結論
「文字列として扱わせたいならstrクラスを継承する」という、ドキュメントに載せるほどでもない当たり前のことでした。

■ソースコード
site-packages/docutils/nodes.py